# Can a Warlock cast a spell at a lower level than their spell slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, warlock

Can a Warlock cast a spell using a lower level slot than the slots they have available?

For example, if a 9th level Warlock (who has 5th slots) comes into a possession of a Shield Guardian (who can store a spell of 4th level or lower), can the Warlock cast a spell using a lower slot for storage into the guardian?

Answer (score 16):

## No

From the warlock's Pact Magic feature, from PHB p. 107 or [here in the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#PactMagic) (emphasis mine):

> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have. The table also shows what level of those slots is; **all of your spell slots are the same level.**

In the section on casting a spell at a higher level, from PHB p. 201 or [here in the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpellataHigherLevel) (emphasis by @Carcer):

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, **the spell assumes the higher level for that casting.**