# Is counterspelling a warlock different?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, spellcasting, counterspelling

My question is about something that happens in [S2E98 of *Critical Role*](https://youtu.be/4OH5Sa8x_Cw?t=17855) (potential spoilers if you haven't watched it yet).

In the episode, the wizard attempts to *counterspell* a *dimension door* spell. The *counterspell* is 4th-level just like *dimension door* normally is; however, the DM mentions that because the caster of *dimension door* is a warlock, it is a 5th-level *dimension door* spell, and the wizard still has to make the spellcasting ability check to see if *counterspell* works.

**Is there some official rule that would explain why counterspelling a warlock would be different?** This could of course be some house rule, but I don't see any hints that this show would have such a house rule.

The warlock is an NPC; his eldritch blast gives 3 shots, so he's at least 11th level. The player characters' party is 11th level.

Comment: Related: "[Can you cast a spell at a higher level, even if it doesn't have an “At higher levels” entry?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45008)" and "[Can a Warlock cast a spell at a lower level than their spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125747)"

Comment: I edited in the name of the show, since a spoiler warning doesn't help much if you don't know what it's spoiling. (And it's likely to be everyone's first guess, anyways.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### The warlock 'upcasts' naturally

Warlocks don't have the options to choose what level of spell slot they use to cast a spell, as other casters do. Their [Pact Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactMagic-387) feature assigns a single spell level for all their spell slots, and all their spells are cast at that level.

The [Warlock Table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheWarlockTable) lists what level their spells are cast at, which depends on their class level.

Normally, [*dimension door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) is a 4th-level spell if cast at its lowest level. However, depending on the level of the warlock, they could be casting at a higher level because all of their spells are cast at that level.

So it's not so much that it's the warlock that makes the difference, but the spell slot level that's used, which depends on the warlock's class level.

Comment: A note that warlock only have a highest level slots would be helpful for people new to 5e or warlocks. It is something easy to miss.

Comment: @Molot oh yes that is the part I missed. I now looked it up and that explains it. I read all the features but somehow ignored the table as in: just standard spell slot table. Could you make an answer out of that?

Comment: @Molot I read his answer as it is because of upcasting and not because he is a Warlock. Which would be wrong, as any other caster has no reason to upcast the spell, it has no added benefit. However I read it again now it does mention that all spells of a warlock are cast at a certain level. It is a bit hidden. NautArch you might want to make that more obvious

Comment: @findusl is that clearer? I'll add citations layer. Unless someone wants to put it in :)

Comment: FWIW, if the Warlock was an NPC Warlock from Volo's Guide, pages 219 - 220, they are 11th level, 17th level, and 14th level for ArchFey, Fiend, and G.O.O and would cast at levels 6, 9, and 7 respectively.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: That last part's incorrect, for their spell slots. Warlock slots only go up to 5th level. Non-NPC warlocks get the Mystic Arcanum feature for each spell level beyond that (once per long rest, for each spell). The NPC version might not get such a feature, and/or some of its innate 1/day spells may be intended to reflect the Mystic Arcanum...

Comment: "any other caster has no reason to upcast the spell, it has no added benefit" isn't completely accurate. A Wizard who's run out of 4th-level spell slots but who really needs to cast Dimension Door might cast it with a 5th-level slot, despite "wasting" the higher level of the slot. It's not going to be a common occurrence, but it could happen and it's worth being aware of this slight upside regarding it being harder to counter.

Comment: Yes indeed it is more clear now. A bit of a controversial situation for me now, because @Molot made his own answer which is very nice of him. But now that you edited it is very similar to yours. I don't know which one to accept.

Comment: @findusl generally you should accept the more helpful one. If you can't decide, know that I won't mind if it means this one and not mine. I'm glad I helped a little, it matters more than few totally virtual points :)

Comment: @V2Blast Oh, yeah, there is that. :-p

Comment: @findusl There's also the situation similar to what's described by OP.  Wizard needs to cast *Dimension Door* to escape.  Knows the enemy is a spellcaster that might have *Counterspell*.  Wizard deliberately upcasts *Dimension Door* in order to reduce the chance of the spell being countered and preventing their escape.

Answer (score 19):

### Warlocks only have highest-level spell slots.*

All spells Warlocks cast are always* cast at the highest-level spell slot available, because that's the only spell slots they have.

Because of that, warlock players and DMs often just don't speak of upcasting aloud. It is something that always happens, so it would get old pretty fast. And that's why if the Warlock had 5th-level slots, the Warlock's *dimension door* was automatically a 5th-level spell without anyone needing to say it.

---

* There may be discussions of whether warlocks could intentionally decide not to upcast if they wanted, but that's out of the scope of this Q&A.